# Highcharts data array not working

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, highcharts

When i try to push array from php to Highcharts, its not working.

```
$rankingsDate = Array (
[0] => 11.07.2016     
[1] => 10.07.2016     
[2] => 09.07.2016     
[3] => 08.07.2016 
)

$rankingsDate = "'" . implode("','", $rankingsDate) . "'";
```

When i add rankingsDate to the category of highscharts it adds double qoutes to the string. when i echo $rankingsDate in php i get below.

```
'11.07.2016','10.07.2016','09.07.2016','08.07.2016'
```

but when i add $rankingsDate to Categories in highcharts in php, it adds double qoutes (") to the string so i get below.

```
"categories":["'11.07.2016','10.07.2016','09.07.2016','08.07.2016'"]
```

My highcharts in php is like below.

```
$yourFirstChart["xAxis"] = array(
            "type" => 'datetime',
            "categories" => [$rankingsDate]);
```

How do push the string to highcharts without getting double qoutes.?

Comment: You declare `$rankingsDate` is a string. How do you pass the `$yourFirstChart` to JavaScript? You probably don't need to `implode` the data at all.

Comment: I tried without implode and now it works :) Thanks.